# Heatmap and Contour figures in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, heatmap, contour, contourf

Suppose that I have this information that first column is feature one of a motor, Second column is feature two and column three is response (in this case performance of motor).

```
[34 56 100
12 12 80 
7 6 60
3 4 20
1 1 10.5
0 0 1]
```

I want have something like `heatmap` or `contour` that for example I have a warmer (for instance red color) for first row in matrix and more light color for row two and etc. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `image()`, the standard colormap, and a clever manipulation of the data. Try this:

```
yourData = [34 56 100;
            12 12 80;
            7  6  60;
            3  4  20;
            1  1  10.5;
            0  0  1];

%// First, normalize each column relative to itself.
normData(:, 1) = yourData(:, 1)/max(max(yourData(:, 1));
normData(:, 2) = yourData(:, 2)/max(max(yourData(:, 2));
normData(:, 3) = yourData(:, 3)/max(max(yourData(:, 3));

%// Next, adjust each column to a particular location on the default colormap
%// Adjust the scale and constant offsets to preference. Lower offsets are cooler.
scale = 5;
scaledData(:, 1) = (scale*normData(:, 1)) + 58;
scaledData(:, 2) = (scale*normData(:, 2)) + 46;
scaledData(:, 3) = (scale*normData(:, 3)) + 20;

image(scaledData);
```

Fun question. Enjoy!

**Update**:

I thought this was a neat problem, so I turned it into a function. Check it out:

```
function scaledData = colorcolumn(C, scale)
    for colNum = 1:size(C, 2)
        normData(:, colNum) = C(:, colNum)/max(max(C(:, colNum)));
        scaledData(:, colNum) = (scale*normData(:, colNum)) + colNum*(64/size(c,2));
    end
end
```

Try this for a neat effect:

```
image(colorcolumn(rand(50,25), 5);
```

Efficiency feedback is welcome.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answer. I checked your code. You normalized data so changed scale of data in heatmap. How can I have my heatmap with real scales? Besides that I simplified my problem to this matrix. My real data has more than 800 samples. Another question. When I checked your hitmap in Matlab, as you know We must warmer colors in higher values of X and Y (first and second columns) but We have warmer color in lower values. Thanks again.

Comment: The 800 samples shouldn't make a difference. As for the normalization... Well, this is probably as good as it's going to get. You have to think about what you really want out if this. If you don't normalize your data there is effectively no way to do what you're asking in a single axis, with a single colormap. You could use three separate axes, but if you wanted to do that, I assume you wouldn't have asked the question. Also, you could normalize to the whole matrix, instead of individual columns. That would preserve the matrix total scale. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. What is your idea about second question? This is the result: http://www.mediafire.com/view/iygtcziliu3luhv/Heatmap.jpg  . We have warmer colors in lower values of X and Y ( first and second columns of matrix)

Comment: Use 'axis xy' and 'axis ij' to flip the axes orientation. Can you tell me what, specifically, you would like to be different about the image you shared?

Comment: I think it is obvious if I truly get your question. We have higher performance in higher combinations of X and Y so my purpose is showing it in heatmap with warmer colors but the image that I shared with you is reverse.

Comment: Ok, to reverse the output you have two options. You can either use the command 'axis xy' or 'axis ij', or you can flip 20 and 58 in the code in my answer.

Comment: Another question. What is purpose of Scale? We are changing scale of X and Y again here?

Comment: I think we are changing again scale of data in last phase by adding 20,46,58. Normalization Is a suitable progress because it doesn't change scale of data but I think adding some different constant numbers is a different story.

Comment: Ok, you must understand that this is a visualization. It shows the relationship between the variables, not their absolute value. The constant addition does nothing except slide the center of the normalized value distribution up the colormap. The 'scale' variable controls how much colorspace the distribution covers, so larger values generate more contrast inside the column. That should be clear if you just tweak the values a bit. Turn on the colorbar in your figure if you're having trouble visualizing this. I promise, this code answers your question, you just have to understand what you asked.

Comment: Thank you for answer again. This heatmap is like a report for me. people who doesn't know about these discussions must get the purpose of it. They ask me why the range is different? what is 3 or 4 meaning in axes? The nearest solution for this scaling problem is that I should have a same range in two axes ( for instance both ranges between 0 and 1 ) . With this the purpose of graph is more clear . What do you think? we have two cases. 1) use raw ranges of data the you said we cant use it. 2) Have a equal range in both axes.

Comment: Ok, we're almost to a shared understanding. I think it would be most clear if you simply removed the axes entirely. You see, the axes don't actually encode any information, so no need to try to impose data on them. You can remove the axis ticks with command: `set(gca,'YTick',[] 'XTick',[]);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your precise answers.